# WAS 8.0 eclipse plugin and hot deployment

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-8

I am using Eclipse Indigo and WebSphere application server v8.0 plugin for a Java EE project.

Setting the publishing option Run server with resources within the workspace makes the project to be redeployed when code is changed. This is fine.

But when I change some xhtml, css or js, no update is made on the server. Because there is an option saying that files with this extensions won't cause a redeploy.

I don't really need a redeploy when I change one of these files. I just need this files to be updated. This works fine with jboss. How can I achieve this using websphere v8.0 and eclipse? To redeploy when classes change, but only update the css, js or xhtml files?

Comment: Hmmm... I haven't seen those static type files not change automatically. Did you force a cache reload in your browser? (Granted I'm on the IBM-enhanced version of Eclipse.)

Comment: Maybe this is the difference then... I am using eclipse indigo, not the IBM-enhanced version

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your web.xml file in your Web application have the refresh period  in -1, maybe this is your problem.

```
<!-- Time in seconds that facelets should be checked for changes since last request.
A value of -1 disables refresh checking. -->

<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
   <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Is there any way to do a hot-replacement of a JavaScript file in WebSphere 8???