# WAS V8.0 Developer Tools - hot deployment of resources (*.xhtml,*.js...) is not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere

I deploy a maven-based EAR from Eclipse Kepler by WAS8.0 Developer Tools to the WebSphere 8.0 AppServer.

Deployment configurations:

I deploy **to the workspace** and selected the field **"never deploy automatically"**. (Because otherwise after a few changes to any resource the auto deployments starts and blocks me from working for at least 5 minutes)

With this configuration I can debug my java code very well. Changes in the java code are recognized by the AppServer without a redeploy or a restart of the server.
But changes to resources like *.xhtml or *.js are recognized by the server only after a restart of the server (that implies a redeploy).

As far as I understand it should be enough if the resources would be copied to the right location in order to be read by the server. (isnt it?)
But I even don't understand from which location the AppServer reads the resources in this mode "deploying to workspace".

What can I do?
What is the location of the resources, where the server reads them from?

I read this Stack Overflow-Question, too: [WAS 8.0 eclipse plugin and hot deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970033/was-8-0-eclipse-plugin-and-hot-deployment)
But that advices did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with static resources when the binaries' output source is not WEB-INF/classes, e.g when using Maven they are stored in /target.

Verify that your Java Build Path has an output folder like this:

```
Maven: YourProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
Without Maven: YourProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't have an effect.

Comment: I can see that WAS reads the resources from following path:`<MyEclipseWorkspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\<MyWar>\....` But this files are not updated when saving in eclipse!

Comment: I solved this by adding a builder copiing the resources to that directory. For people knowing German :-( I made a detailed description here: [link] http://sezok.de/eclipsewas/WAS8Plugin.html